# dockerfile for selenium. 255 driver initialization error

Tags: python, django, docker, selenium, dockerfile

There is a part of django that sends information via an API to be processed by selenium. There are problems with building docker under selenium. 255 selenium error in logs. I've already broken my head. Please tell me what could be the problem. latest version of geckodriver

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9
LABEL autor="LOADER"
LABEL description="APP"

WORKDIR /usr/src/html_loader/
COPY . /usr/src/html_loader/

RUN apt-get update

RUN echo "Y" | apt-get install alien
RUN echo "Y" | apt-get install gunicorn
RUN echo "Y" | apt-get install memcached
RUN echo "Y" | apt-get install unixodbc
RUN echo "Y" | apt-get install unixodbc-dev
RUN echo "Y" | apt-get install cifs-utils
RUN echo "Y" | apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
RUN echo "Y" | apt-get install libgtk-3-0
RUN echo "Y" | apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-2
RUN echo "Y" | apt-get install xvfb

RUN apt-get install libaio1

RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN echo "Y" | apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends firefox
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget bzip2 libxtst6 libgtk-3-0 libx11-xcb-dev libdbus-glib-1-2 libxt6 libpci-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV pip=pip3
ENV python=python3
ENV DJANGO_HOST="http://crawlerdjango:4333"

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change
RUN Xvfb &

EXPOSE 4666
EXPOSE 4777
```

It's funny, but two days ago the code worked

Comment: Can you show us the log?

Comment: Update the question with the error logs.

Comment: Today when running docker this code works as expected